# Difficulty mantaining value of a variable during Recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to count inversions in an array using divide and conquer methodology.However, I'm unable to mantain the Total of inversions .After the program is done it returns the number of inversions in the last step and not the sum of all the inversions done before it.

```
def mergesort(A):
 if len(A) <2:
    return A
 mid = len(A)//2
 lefthalf = A[:mid]
 righthalf = A[mid:]
 mergesort(lefthalf)
 mergesort(righthalf)
 Total= merge(lefthalf,righthalf,A)
 return Total

def merge(left,right,A):
 Total = 0
 i,j,k = 0,0,0
 while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
     if left[i] <= right[j]:
         A[k] = left[i]
         i+=1
         k+=1
     else:
         A[k] = right[j]
         j+=1
         k+=1
         Total+= len(left[i:]) 
 while i < len(left):
      A[k] = left[i]
      i+=1
      k+=1
 while j < len(right):
      A[k] = right[j]
      j+=1
      k+=1  
 return Total
```

print (mergesort([1,5,3,2,4]))

How can I mantain the Total ?
Please suggest neccesary changes to code with explanation.
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `Total += mergesort(left half)` and `Total += mergesort(righthalf)`? The return values from these recursive calls aren't currently being used.

Comment: there is ` return Total
 return A` in your routine. Which one is it ?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre return Total

Comment: @TabishBashir Then you need to return 0 in your base case `if len(A)<2`...

Comment: @ gowrath Don,t all inversions get counted during merge step since the sorting takes place there?

Comment: @TabishBashir For the current step yes, but the recursive calls `mergesort(left half)` and `mergesort(right half)` are also doing inversions that you need to consider. Either you need to use the return value, or make total a global variable defined outside the methods.

Comment: @gowrath  Thanks i defined a global variable. It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, here is an answer so this question doesn't remain in the unanswered section.

Your total needs to keep track of the number of inversions not just in the current stack frame, but also the stack frame of future recursive calls. To this end, either you need to add the return value of the recursive calls to Total, or declare Total as a global variable that will be shared amongst each recursive call as opposed to keeping a local variable as you have now.